# How can I find object in array in a string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

So I have an array that looks as such:

```
std::string Operators[4] = {
  "+",
  "-",
  "*",
  "/"
};
```

And I have another string, that looks like this

```
std::string Equation = "1+1";
```

I'm trying to make the code check if the plus from the array is in the equation string. Is it no different than finding a substring in a string? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you made the first array an array of strings, instead of an array of characters? If all of the strings are only one character long, then it would make more sense to make the first array an array of characters.

Comment: True, I could have done that, I've just now fixed that.

Comment: Have a look at `string::find_first_of` or `std::any_of`.

Comment: If the final goal is to create a calculator, reading up on the Shunting Yard Algorithm may be helpful.

Comment: The goal isn't to make a calculator, I'm trying to be able to convert strings into arithmetic equations, however that may work, so I might use that

Answer (score 1):

Go through the member functions of [std::string class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and specifically, for your purpose, check the **Search** member functions.

Below is an example of using `find` member function of `std::string` class for finding *Operators* in *Equation*:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::string Operators[4] = {
      "+",
      "-",
      "*",
      "/"
    };
    
    std::string Equation = "1+1";
 
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(Operators)/sizeof(Operators[0]); ++i) {
        std::string::size_type n = Equation.find(Operators[i]);

        std::cout << Operators[i] << " : ";
        if (n == std::string::npos) {
            std::cout << "not found\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "found at position : " << n << '\n';
        }
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
+ : found at position : 1
- : not found
* : not found
/ : not found
```

Note that, in the above program, if you change the type of `Operators` array to

```
char Operators[4] = {
  '+',
  '-',
  '*',
  '/'
};
```

it will work absolutely fine without any other change because the `find` member function has an overload which takes `char` as argument.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it does not seem different. Maybe the issue was what the commenter said, changing your array of strings to an array of chars. Regardless this code works for your scenario:

```
int main() {

  std::string str = "1+1";
  
  char Operators[4] = {'+','-','*','/'}; // using the commenters suggestion, char array is better

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
      if (Operators[i] == str[j])
        std::cout << "A '" << Operators[i] << "' is present" << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;

}
```

As another commenter said, you could also use an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

use find_first_of

```
 std::string Equation = "1+1";

 std::size_t found = Equation.find_first_of("+-/*");
```

if char is found  'found' will be the offset (1 in this case). If not found then 'found' will equal std::string::npos

See

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/

To know which operator was found do

```
   char op = Equation[found];
```